# Dynamically translating liferay's portlets - pootle

Tags: liferay, translation, jython, portlet, pootle

I'm looking for some tool, which provide me possibility to dynamically (online) translate portlets in liferay. I mean, I wrote portlet in English, but people from other country may want to use it with their own language, and they can want to make translation. I know that there is Pootle tool, but I'm looking something what I can launch on Java (JBoss). There is a Jython, but I'm newbie on that, and I don't know how run pootle on jython. If someone have idea about way to solve my problem, please help.

Or maybe more simple **Is there possibility to deploy pootle as war file in application server ?**

regards

Answer (score 0):

To your simplified question: Pootle is a Python application - AFAIK those get rarely packaged as WAR files. It might be possible, but I've never tried it...

That said, the sweet spot of Pootle is to prepare software translations and bring them back into the software development process - e.g. build. Do you want to "live update" your language files or are you ok with exporting them to your build system, then redeploying the updated plugins? If you want to do live-updates, pootle might not be the right system for you.

If you want to use the translations in the development process (e.g. in buildscripts), your real question might be "How do I install pootle?" - but for this you'd have to give some more steps that you tried, what worked and what did not work.

I never installed pootle myself, but I won't expect it to run seamlessly on a Java application server. If you've never done so as well, rather go the easy way and follow the standard installation procedure.

Comment: Thank you for response. I've decide to write translate Manager on my own from scrach.